# Issues with test-ng parallel execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, parallel-execution

I am not sure if this is a problem with the latest test-ng version, or it was there earlier too (never ran tests in parallel tbh), but.
I configured my testng.xml file to run tests in parallel, it kinda doesn't work.
Based on the thread-count specified, it launches parallel webdriver instances though, but the driver tries to execute everything on the latest instances of the webdriver.

This is how the beginning of my `testng.xml` looks like-

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Parallel Tests" configfailurepolicy="continue" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
```

so now what for a login test class(with 5 login tests), this launches 5 browser windows, goes to the login URL, and enters credentials on the latest browser window session 5 times!

I am initializing the webdriver in my `TestBase.class`. And every other class inherits this. Here's the piece of code where I am initializing the webdriver-

```
public void initialize() {

        browserName = prop.getProperty("browser", "chrome");
        browserMode = prop.getProperty("browser_mode", "start-maximized");

        System.out.println("Launching the browser...");
        if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--"+browserMode);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }
}
```

I am certainly doing something wrong, couldn't figure out what!? Anyone else faced/facing this?

Comment: Show us your test code where your driver is initialized.

Comment: edited the question with the said piece of code included